# Kibana match documents based on keys from different document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to find the unique count of documents matched on keys from different documents.

I have two documents in the same ES index:

```
{
    "appVersion": [301],
    "uri": "www.something.com?productTransactionId=IS3243"
}
```

and

```
{
    "tripId":"IS3243",
    "event":"my_event"
}
```

I want to find out unique count of documents where `event` is `my_event` and `tripId` of second document exist in `uri` of first document and `appVersion` is `301`.

Is it possible in Kibana?